# How to connect Adafruit SPH0645 I2S to nanopi neo air board

Tags: audio, microphone, nanopi

I'm trying to connect an Adafruit SPH0645 I2S microphone to a nanopi neo air board.

What are the steps to follow in order to get this mic working on this board?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check the wiki for the  `FriendlyARM audio hat`. It uses `I2S`

http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoHat_PCM5102A

And the wiki for the `NEO Air-LTS`  http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO_Air

There is an IRC channel called `#friendlyELEC` on `#freenode` where you can get help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I tried using wiki , but info it is not enough , even tried to use the mic with the PCM5102A but still didn't manage to have it working.On a Raspi I managed to have it working using this tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test but on a Nanopi no luck.